# How can I make Alexa recognize number "two" and "four" in my utterance

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I got a trouble about Alexa Number type. When I try to command number "two" or "four" Alexa always returns an undefined value or "?" to my server.

My utterance is as below:

**echo, tell machine "Machinename" "action" "......".**

- "machine" is skill invocation.
- "Machinename" is AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER. I also tried it as AMAZON.NUMBER.
- the second and third component is custom type and they are OK.

I have read almost topic related to this issue. I found solution {two|Machinename} is not worked with me. The Alexa skill kit always reponds as

*"The built-in slot type "{two | Machinename}" cannot be extended with custom values. Error code: InextensibleSlot".*

because "AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER" and "AMAZON.NUMBER" is not extensible Built-In Types.

- In another case when i tried to move "Machinename" to the last slot in my utterance. It still did not work. All numbers are ok except "two" and "four". So looks like it not related to invocation with "to" or "for".

Anyone please give me a solution or workaround.

ps: sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can update the question with interaction model

Comment: Thank for your help! I will try with your solution.

Comment: I didn't mention any solution, can you share the interaction model from JSON editor in your skill builder

Answer (score 0):

I tried your interaction model with `AMAZON.NUMBER` instead of `AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER` and everything  is working fine. Slot values are mapped correctly.

Ex: **ask machine number four start printing**

Request generated:

```
"request": {
        ....
            "machinename": {
                    "name": "machinename",
                    "value": "4",
        ....
            "actionname": {
                    "name": "actionname",
                    "value": "start",
        ....
            "functionname": {
                    "name": "functionname",
                    "value": "printing",
        ....
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank for your help! but are you using testing mode or any simulator? I tried AMAZON.NUMBER also AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER they alway OK with text simulator. But when i try with voice command from TTS or human voice it will be false!

Comment: I will absolutely try it again! Thank for your support!

Answer (score 0):

After about 2 week i try to contact with Amazon also fine solution from the Internet. This times they can't help anything.

From the Amazon support team, they alway tell me recheck AMAZON.NUM/AMAZON.FOUR_DEGIT_NUMBER. I told them it alway ok with simulator and ask for help from real devices. But don't have any response as expected.
So this times, i tried to resolve this issue by another way:

- AMAZON.SearchQuery ==> receive command string and process it yourself instead of slots.
- Dialog Management.

Hope this helps